# ProviderIncompatibleException with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I always get this error when I issue this command

```
http://localhost:19572/api/courses
```

This method is generating the exception

```
public IQueryable GetAllCourses()
{
    return _ctx.Courses
               .Include(“CourseSubject”)
               .Include(“CourseTutor”)
               .AsQueryable();
}
```

Exception:

> System.Data.Entity.CoreProviderIncompatibleException`occurred in`EntityFramework.dll` but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

and when I inspect the JSON element in Fiddler I always get this

> ExceptionMessage=The system cannot find the file specified
>   ExceptionType=System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>   Message=An error has occurred.

I am using Entity Framework 6.0.1, and I have tried 5 but it didn’t work so I there any thing wrong with Entity Framework version or what?

Comment: Did you check the possible error that message mentions - *an incorrect connection string* ?

Comment: here is the link for my drive folder there are the project i don't know maybe it will work on your computer https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=ac25d7a2dc192bdb!13631&authkey=!AJIYDQ0vhYY1Uzk&ithint=folder%2c and this is the blog i followed http://bitoftech.net/2013/11/25/building-database-model-entityframework-code-first